# Reversing the order of key-value pairs in a dictionary (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary, reversing

How do I reverse the order of key-value pairs of a dictionary, in Python? For example, I have this dictionary:

```
{"a":1, "b":2, "c":3}
```

I want to reverse it so that it returns:

```
{"c":3, "b":2, "a":1}
```

Is there a function that I haven't heard about that can do this? Some lines of code is fine as well.

Answer (score 7):

Dictionary does not have any sense of order , so your key/value pairs are not ordered in any format.

If you want to preserve the order of the keys, you should use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) from the start, instead of using normal dictionary , Example -

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> d = OrderedDict([('a',1),('b',2),('c',3)])
>>> d
OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)])
```

OrderedDict would preserve the order in which the keys were entered into the dictionary. In above case, it would be the order in which the keys existed in the list - `[('a',1),('b',2),('c',3)]` - `'a' -> 'b' -> 'c'`

Then you can get the reversed order of keys using `reversed(d)` , Example -

```
>>> dreversed = OrderedDict()
>>> for k in reversed(d):
...     dreversed[k] = d[k]
...
>>> dreversed
OrderedDict([('c', 3), ('b', 2), ('a', 1)])
```

Comment: Yes correct, that is not the point , its that sorted would sort it , OP does not want to `sort` , OP wants keys in reverse order.

Comment: This does not apply with Python 3.6 and newer. Dictionaries preserve order nowadays

Answer (score 0):

```
#The dictionary to be reversed
dict = {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"}

#Append the keys of the dictionary in a list
list_keys = []
for k in dict.keys():
    list_keys.append(k)

rev_dict = {}
#Traverse through the reversed list of keys and add them to a new dictionary
for i in reversed(list_keys):
    rev_dict[i] = dict[I]
print(rev_dict)

#OUTPUT: {'key3': 'value3', 'key2': 'value2', 'key1': 'value1'}
```

Answer (score -1):

A dictionary uses Hashmap to store Key and corresponding values.

Look at : [Is a Python dictionary an example of a hash table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114830/is-a-python-dictionary-an-example-of-a-hash-table)

Anything related to hash has no order.

You can do it with this:

```
d = {}
d['a']=1
d['b']=2
d['c']=3
d['d']=4
print d
for k,v in sorted(d.items(),reverse = True):
    print k,v
```

`d.items()` returns a list of tuples : `[('a', 1), ('c', 3), ('b', 2), ('d', 4)]` and `k,v` gets the values in tuples to iterate in loop.
`sorted()` returns a sorted list, whereas you cannot `use d.items().sort()` which does not return, but instead tries to overwrite the `d.items()`.

Answer (score -1):

This will work. 
Based on Venkateshwara's that didn't work for me 'as is'.

```
def reverse(self):
    a = self.yourdict.items()
    b = list(a) # cast to list from dict_view
    b.reverse() # actual reverse
    self.yourdict = dict(b) # push back reversed values
```

Answer (score -2):

```
d={"a":1, "b":2, "c":3}
x={}
for i in sorted(d.keys(),reverse=True):
    x[i]=d[i]
print(x)
```