# Confusion in hashing used by LSH

Tags: python, hash, nearest-neighbor, locality-sensitive-hash, bigdata

[image]

Matrix `M` is the signatures matrix, which is produced via Minhashing of the actual data, has documents as columns and words as rows. So a column represents a document.

Now it says that every stripe (`b` in number, `r` in length) has its columns hashed, so that a column falls in a bucket. If two columns fall in the same bucket, for >= 1 stripes, then they are potentially similar.

So that means that I should create `b` hashtables and find `b` independent hash functions? Or just one is enough and every stripe sends its columns to the same collections of buckets (but wouldn't this cancel the stripes)?

Would a dictionary be enough for a hashtable in this case<sup>*</sup>?

*<sub>[Is a Python dictionary an example of a hash table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114830/is-a-python-dictionary-an-example-of-a-hash-table)</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out, posting for future readers.

I am going to use one dictionary, since the slides mentioned that it's OK to use the same hash function for every stripe ([dictionaries do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37100390/towards-understanding-dictionaries)).

Every bucket will be a key for our dictionary.

On insertion, a document (i.e. a column which belongs in a stripe) will be passed by a hash function (which *we* will create) and the result should be a key. That way our dictionary will be populated.