# How do you write Python's dict with a different hash function and collision resolution strategy?

Tags: python, cpython

I'd like to write my own `dict` container like the built-in `dict` but with a different hash function and collision resolution strategy.

`PyDictObject`, as `Include\cpython\dictobject.h` defines it, doesn't require change, but I'd like to write a different version of `_Py_dict_lookup` compared to the code in `Objects\dictobject.c`. (I'm referring to files in [the CPython repository](https://github.com/python/cpython).)

What's a (simple) way to be able to change/add new files so that after rebuilding the interpreter, I can have

```
a = dict('key'='value')
b = my_dict('key2'='value2')
```

run successfully such that `my_dict` has a different hash table implementation (written in C, like `dict` does)?

Comment: Are you asking about the process of compiling the CPython source code, or how to actually implement a different dictionary in C?

Comment: Compiling a separate extension should be easier than modifying and compiling the whole interpreter.

Comment: Note that the standard `dict` implementation doesn't define a hash function - instead, *each individual object type* (that is suitable for use as a dict key) defines its own `__hash__()` method.  If you really want to change that, you've got a *lot* of work ahead of you...

Comment: Maybe this can answer your question about the hash function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37104288/15826727 . Although I'm not sure if a wrapping object is sufficient in your case.

Comment: @mkrieger1 a different dictionary