# How to hash lists?

Tags: python, list, hash, nearest-neighbor, locality-sensitive-hash

Lists are not hashable. However, I am [implementing LSH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37089971/confusion-in-hashing-used-by-lsh) and I am *seeking for a hash function* that will correspond a list of positive integers (in [1, 29.000]) to k buckets. The number of lists is D, where D > k (I think) and D = 40.000, where k is not yet known (open to suggestions).

---

Example (D = 4, k = 2):

```
118 | 27 | 1002 | 225
128 | 85 | 2000 | 8700
512 | 88 | 2500 | 10000
600 | 97 | 6500 | 24000
800 | 99 | 7024 | 25874
```

The first column should be given as input to the hash function and return the number of a bucket.

---

What confuses me is that we do not seek for a function to hash a number, but a column, i.e. a list of positive integers.

Any ideas please?

<sub>I am using [python](/questions/tagged/python) if that matters</sub>

Comment: How about just converting it to hashable types, such as tuple? ( ex. hash(tuple([1, 2, 3])) )

Comment: @hunminpark you mean something like `print hash(tuple([1,2,3,4,5]))`? That is what @lejlot suggested, but he deleted his answer..

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean you want to take a list and produce a single bucket index, or do you want to take a list of length `n` and produce `n` bucket indices?

Comment: @mobiusklein the first. Input is a list of positive integers -> h -> index of bucket.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just convert it in a hashable type before:

```
In [4]: hash(l)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

hash(tuple(l)) % k  # 29000
Out[5]: 70846
```