# Behaviour of Python Sets

Tags: python-3.x, set

```
s={['list']}
```

Gives error as below:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
> ```

```
s=set(['list'])
```

However above works fine. Why?

Comment: The first example should be a `SyntaxError` since you can't define a set that way. You can use either `{}` or `set()` to define a set.

Comment: Did you mean `s = {['list']}`. In python 3.6.0 your code gives a SyntaxError. But this gives the error you posted.

Comment: It was a typo. Corrected the same

Answer (score 2):

Your first example should be giving you a `SyntaxError`.

`{['list']}` is a set containing a list which raises an error because [lists are not hashable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37136878/list-unhashable-but-tuple-hashable).
`set(['list'])` is a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-set) *built from* an iterable that happens to be a list.  The equivalent expression using curly braces would be `{'list'}`, which works fine because strings are hashable.

Comment: It was a typo.Corrected the same.

Answer (score 1):

**The first example is not valid because lists are unhashable.**

`{['list']}` is read as a `set` containing a single item of type `list`, but lists cannot be used as set items or keys in python, so you get an error.

The closest analogue would be to use a tuple `{('list')}`, since tuples are hashable, but it seems more likely that you just want the string, in which case you should write:

```
s = {'list'}
```

**The second example is valid python syntax.**

It calls the set constructor on a list of items to get a set of those items.

Comment: It was a typo.Corrected the same.

Comment: Yup! I edited the answer to reflect the edited question.