# Convert a list of integer to a list of predefined strings in Python

Tags: python

How to convert a list `[0,1,2,1]` to a list of string, when we convert 0 to 'abc', 1 to 'f' and 2 to 'z'? So the output list will be `['abc','f','z','f']`.

I did:

```
x = []
for i in xrange(input):
  if input[i] == ...
    x.append ('abc')
```

Comment: How about use dict as a map? For example, map=dict(0='abc'), then map['0'] = 'abc'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is a Python dictionary an example of a hash table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114830/is-a-python-dictionary-an-example-of-a-hash-table)

Comment: OP, did either of the proposed answers answer your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a dictionary as your translation table:

```
old_l = [0, 1, 2, 1]
trans = {0: 'abc', 1: 'f', 2: 'z'}
```

Then, to translate your list:

```
new_l = [trans[v] for v in old_l]
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to a dict, if you can guarantee that the numbers are sequential, you can just use a list and indexes:

```
subs = ['abc','f','z'] 
original = [0, 1, 2, 1]

result = [subs[x] for x in original]
```

Same idea as the dict, but marginally less to type?